# it's live vs. it's on live

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

Does "it's live" mean something that someone would say it at a party?

And "it's on live" means to be broadcasting at the same time, as in *live news*?

In the following sentence:

> I wanted to ask my teacher if this online class is going to be *on live*/*live*,

which one should I use?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either one.

> I wanted to ask my teacher if this online class is going to be **live**.

*live* means it is not "prerecorded". You can also use this for a party:

> I wanted to ask my friend if the entertainment at the party is going to be **live**.

*live* means there will be in-person performances, as opposed to recorded music or such.

And the other case...

> I wanted to ask my teacher if this online class is going to be **on (TV) live**.

Where *TV* is understood and could be left out. Here *on* refers to the medium used (TV), not the state (live or prerecorded).

Comment: So can I ask this in both ways? "Is this online class going to be live?" And "is this online class going to be on live?" @user3169

Comment: As I said, the second one needs to have a medium (where it is "on") specified. Without that, it sounds odd to me, though technically it could be implied and not stated, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word/construction you're looking for is *live*, without preposition.

- You can say "it's live!" referred to a party with the meaning of:

  > jumping, full of people, exciting. [Referred to] something that was very enjoyable:
  >   
  >  *That rave was live* 
  >   
  >  *The place was live*
  >   
  >  ([Urban Dictionary](http://live.urbanup.com/112553))
- you can use the word *live* as an adverb, meaning:

  > broadcast as it ​happens; ​performing or being ​performed in ​front of an ​audience: *I've got two ​tickets to ​see them (​perform) live.*
  >   
  >  ([Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/live))

  Or are you referring to the service named *[OnLive](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OnLive)* (which has a different purpose, though)?